# No Object Found FB API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Hi all no matter what i send to the facebook api using composer i get  a no object found error. There is campaign data from the date range set. The campaign is inactive and not delivering so i set that from the facebook walkthrough.

Here is my PHP also note i blocked out the access token information but that was auto generated by facebook so it should be good no? The account i created the app in is the one that setup the campaign im trying to pull data for

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdsInsights;
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;

$access_token = '[ACCESS TOKEN]';
$ad_account_id = 'act_[ACC ID]';
$app_secret = '[APP SECRET]';

$api = Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
$api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());

$fields = array(
  'adgroup_id',
  'campaign_group_id',
  'campaign_group_name',
  'campaign_id',
  'campaign_name',
  'clicks',
  'cpc',
  'cpm',
);
$params = array(
  'time_range' => array('since' => '2017-03-01','until' => '2017-03-25'),
  'filtering' => array(array('field' => 'delivery_info','operator' => 'IN','value' => array('inactive','completed','recently_completed','active','limited','not_delivering','not_published','rejected')),array('field' => 'cpm','operator' => 'GREATER_THAN','value' => '0'),array('field' => 'impressions','operator' => 'GREATER_THAN','value' => '0'),array('field' => 'cpa','operator' => 'GREATER_THAN','value' => '0')),
  'level' => 'adset',
  'breakdowns' => array(),
);
echo json_encode((new AdAccount($ad_account_id))->getInsights(
  $fields,
  $params
)->getResponse()->getContent(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

And this is the response i get from the terminal

```
"curl -G \
-d 'time_range={"since":"2017-03-31","until":"2017-06-01"}' \
-d 'filtering=[{"field":"delivery_info","operator":"IN","value":["active","limited","completed","recently_completed"]}]' \
-d 'level=adset' \
-d 'breakdowns=[]' \
-d 'fields=cpm,impressions,spend,today_spend,account_id,account_name,adgroup_id,adgroup_name,campaign_group_name,campaign_id,campaign_name,date_start,date_stop,clicks,ctr,total_action_value,cost_per_action_type:link_click' \
-d 'access_token=[TOKEN]' \
-d 'appsecret_proof=[APP SECRET]' \
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/105234613463666/insights
Fatal error: Uncaught exception
```

'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message 'Unsupported get request. Object with ID '105234613463666' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api' in /Users/UserAccount/facebook-php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Exception/RequestException.php:140"

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

figured out why, the documentation is terrible for the facebook app, i must request access to use certain features of their API even with a dev account and a token where i have specified ads account access (doesnt implement until they review your app).

You can close this thread.

Thanks